# Comparing records of tables based on composite key

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have a job to refresh a look up table data for which I need help. I have 2 tables with data, one is the existing version (table1) and the other is the new version (table2). The primary key for each of the tables is a composite key. I know there is a different number of rows in each one and I need to find out the differences. Let's assume that the 2 columns part of the composite primary key to be named column1 and column2.

Typically, in the "normal" primary key set-up, I would just look for primary key values NOT IN the list of primary keys from the other table. But I don't know how to do this with a composite primary key.

I found a similar thread for SQL Server but that doesn't seem to work in my case, not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

[How can I compare rows from 2 tables that have composite primary keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435869/how-can-i-compare-rows-from-2-tables-that-have-composite-primary-keys)

Can someone help me compare the rows from these two tables in Oracle/PostgreSQL?

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM b WHERE b.x = a.x AND b.y = a.y);` BTW: this hat nothing to do with primary keys; it works for non-key columns just as well.

Comment: The `FULL JOIN` query will work in both Postgres and Oracle.

Comment: What do you want as output? All columns from the tables? Or just the PK values?

Comment: @ypercube: Thank you for taking time to help on this request. I jsut needed the Primary key values and I was able to get the result from the previous answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT ...
FROM a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM b
  WHERE b.x = a.x AND b.y = a.y
  );
```

BTW: this hat nothing to do with primary keys; it works for non-key columns just as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could even use `NOT IN` with composite values. Example:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

But other syntax variants are typically simpler / faster / more reliable:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

`NOT EXISTS` like [@wildplasser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28858782/939860) posted is a good candidate for best performance.